# How to get rid of UINavigationController after doing a segue to a UITabBarController in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I basically want to "get rid" of the NavigationController I have set up for my login/registration NavigationController after the login/registration has been successful. Basically, I am doing a manual segue after executing some code that runs through an IBAction when the Login/Register button is pressed. My code runs just fine, but the thing is that whenever the segue executes, my second view controller, a TabBarController (which I want to somewhat make independent of the NavigationController) still has the navigation bar on top of the view (with the `<Back` button). I am doing the transition through a push segue, which kind of makes me realize that it is not the correct approach since it means I am nesting the TabBarController into the NavigationController itself. It's just that I do not know how to make it independent.

My approach is the following:

```
//...After various checks/functions, inside a function, I redirect myself to the TabBarController

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("redirectToMenuFromRegistration", sender: nil)

//Where the segue "redirectToMenuFromRegistration" is my TabBarController..
```

As I said, I do not want my TabBarController to be nested within my NavigationController, I want it to be somehow independent. Now another question. If I do this, will I still be able to pass data through ViewControllers?

Thank you so much for your help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set segue "Show" to "Present Modally" in storyboard.

[image]